Autoplay feature of antd's Carousel working inconsistently
Sometimes the Carousel goes through the images as expected, other times it seems to "fall asleep" and is unresponsive. Has anyone had a similar issue?
<Carousel
autoplay
autoplaySpeed={8000}
ref={ref}
dots={true}
className={custom-carousel ${dotClass}}
>
{data.heroes.map((item) => (



))}

